# No business POIs shown on GMSMapView, didTapPOIWithPlaceID not called

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm showing a `GMSMapView`, but can't achieve to have business places like restaurants, hotels, shops, etc shown. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/poi) using the mapType `kGMSTypeNormal` should provide that request.

> In addition, business POIs appear by default on the map when the map type is kGMSTypeNormal

Unfortunately, it only shows "official" POIs like parks, sights, hospitals and alike.

Furthermore I would have expected that the `GMSMapViewDelegate` member function `mapView:didTapPOIWithPlaceID:name:location:` is called when I tap one of these "official" POIs, but no matter where I tap, I don't get the function to be called. I temporarily tried the corresponding `mapView:didTapAtCoordinate:` just to make sure I set up the delegate correctly and this works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class PoiGoogleMapVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainMap: GMSMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainMap.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self

        let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 48.857165, longitude: 2.354613, zoom: 8.0)
        self.mainMap.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
        self.mainMap.camera = camera
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapPOIWithPlaceID placeID: String, name: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped \(name): \(placeID), \(location.latitude)/\(location.longitude)")
    }
}
```

What might be a hint to the solution, but at this point only confuses me, is that according to the [api doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#ac85e7294d5634a7e7b5c2ceafc1b1e80) `GMSMapView` has a property called `mapStyle`. When I try to access this property Xcode gives me a compiler error:

> Value of type 'GMSMapView' has no member 'mapStyle'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mapStyle` and business POIs were added in version 2.1, released on 22 September 2016. See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases#version_21_-_september_22_2016

Maybe you have an older version of the SDK?

Comment: That is the correct answer. It was also my suspicion, but since I installed it from scratch, I couldn't believe it. Turns out it doesn't hurt (and sometimes can be really useful) if you do a `pod update` right after your `pod install`. Thanks!